# ROSCORE server on android

Tags: ros, wifi, roscore, rosserial-client, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to run a ROSCORE or a minified version of it on an Android phone?

What i want to do is i have a ROS Node A and Android cellphone B without a ROS MASTER (Ubuntu). A and B will be either linked via wifi or bluetooth and i want to gather information from Node A to Android B.

Is it possible to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286705/roscore-server-on-android/) by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. I can't find it in the docs on the ROS Wiki at the moment, but from [Running a roscore in an android smartphone](https://wiki.epfl.ch/roscontrol/roscore-android-smartphone):

[image: image description]

Clicking either `New Publish Master` or `New Private Master` will create a ROS master on the Android device.

The private instance will not be accessible by other hosts, the public one will be.

---

Edit: note that you're not actually running `roscore` (ie: the actual program itself) on the phone this way, but a Java re-implementation that offers similar services over xml-rpc.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on 2018-03-27**:
Thank you gvdhoorn ! I will try this out :)